# xml elements or python-docx. how to delete specific rows

Tags: python, xml, python-docx

I could not find how to delete specific rows in python-docx.

I need to delete all the rows after the 3rd one in a table of a document.

I found how to delete a specific row (the 3rd one for example) using xml elements:

```
import docx
from docx import Document
document = Document('filename')

table = document.tables[0]

rowA=table.rows[3]
table_element=table._tbl
row_element=rowA._tr
table_element.remove(row_element)
document.save('filename')
```

How can I delete all the rows after the 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested this code, but guess you can use `getnext()`[[1](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html)] method to iterate through all remaining rows. `getnext` as said in the documentation: `Returns the following sibling of this element or None.`

```py
...
row_element = rowA._tr
next_row = row_element.getnext()
while next_row is not None:
    table_element.remove(next_row)
    next_row = row_element.getnext()
...
```

NOTE: this code works assuming there are only table rows as sibling elements (there could be bookmarks etc...) it would probably make sense to add check `if next_row.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}tr'`